# Ionic 2/3 Mocking Toasts

Tags: unit-testing, ionic2, toast

I am having trouble in Ionic 2/3 testing components/pages that utilize ionic components that involve overlays (Alert, Toast, Modal, ActionSheet). When any code calls .present() on the above components, I get the following error.

```
_getPortal is not a function()
```

I have tried mocking the appropriate controller, but that does not seem to be the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Page Code

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public viewCtrl: ViewController) {}

save() {
if (this.object.validate()) {
  this.provider.save(this.object).then(() => {
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error saving object: ", error);
  });
} else {
  let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: 'All fields (except notes) must be filled before you can save a record',
    duration: 3000,
    dismissOnPageChange: true,
    cssClass: "toastError"
  });toast.present();
}}

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AddRecordPage);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
});

afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
    comp = null;
    de = null;
    el = null;
});
```

any code that tests this save method will fail with the _getPortal error

UPDATE:
I have further isolated down to the App Object it appears as that is where _getPortal throws the error from; however, I do have my primary app object injected.....

Comment: can you post code of a page where you call any of these components?

Comment: I can't post the whole page due to company policy but this is the general method that fails

Comment: what is `comp`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to mock your app to get around this issue, ionic-angular provides a mock you can use... I.E:

```
import { mockApp } from 'ionic-angular/util/mock-providers';

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     {provide: App, useValue: mockApp()},
  })
  //etc
}
```

Before you create your testbed component.